# Reference initialization in C++11 default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct X {};

struct Y { 
    Y() = default;
    X& x;
};
```

works fine in C++11. I wish to know how Y::x is actually initialized behind the scenes?

Comment: This code as-is compiles, but I think it won't the moment you actually try to instantiate a `Y`.

Comment: That can't possibly compile. A trivial default constructor default-initializes all members, but references cannot be default-initialized.

Comment: @Alex it works, for certain values of 'works'.

Comment: @KerrekSB: So I guess it boils down to a quality of implementation thing, let's hope compilers catch up to diagnose this sooner rather than later!

Comment: @MatthieuM. its a matter of taste if this should be diagnosed. `default` according to the standard means "do whatever a generated default constructor would be - (even if that means implicit deletion)". However, many compilers warn about the implicit deletion and imo should continue to do so if the constructor is defaulted explicitly.

Comment: @KerrekSB it compiles because as in C++03, even explicitly defaulted ctors are generated only if they are actually called.

Comment: @ArneMertz: Good point! You should make that an answer, with a quote (12.1/6 I believe).

Comment: @KerrekSB has been done already by Michael Burr ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't compile in any major compiler. It will compile, until of creation of object of type `Y`.

If you create object of type `Y`, output of clang will be

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'Y'
note: explicitly defaulted function was implicitly deleted here
    Y() = default;
note: default constructor of 'Y' is implicitly deleted because field
'x' of reference type 'X &' would not be initialized
    X& x;
```

When you declare `user-defined` constructor, which is simply empty function, there is error, without creation of object.

Michael Burr is right. An implicitly-defaulted constructor works perfectly fine. There is no problems with diagnostic here, as I can see.

Answer (score 13):

Even though you explicitly indicate that `Y()` should be defaulted, the compiler is obligated to delete the default constructor under certain conditions (emphasis added):

> 8.4.2/4  Explicitly-defaulted functions
>
> Explicitly-defaulted functions and implicitly-declared functions are
>   collectively called defaulted functions, and the implementation shall
>   provide implicit definitions for them (12.1 12.4, 12.8), **which might
>   mean defining them as deleted**

and

> 12.1/5 Constructors:
>
> ...
>
> ... A defaulted default constructor for class X is defined as deleted if:
>
> - any non-static data member with no brace-or-equal-initializer is of reference type

But it's not an error to define a deleted function or constructor unless you actually try to use it:

> 8.4.3/2 Deleted defintions
>
> A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly,
>   other than to declare it, is ill-formed.

Comment: An important additional point is in my opinion 12.1/6: the defaulted constructor is defined if and when it is ODR-used, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

It "works" if you don't make a Y object. Once you make one you will get an error:

(GCC 4.8.0)

> error: uninitialized reference member in 'struct Y'